# mysql fetchone is returning object when it should return None

Tags: python, mysql

Trying to learn python and making a mysql connection, I expect below code using fetchone to return *None* in below code but it it is returning a object, can someone help understand the behavior.

```
import mysql.connector as m
con=m.connect(host='localhost',
user='root',
password='mysql',
database='reva')

cs3=con.cursor()
                    
q='select * from toy where tid="10111"' 
print(q)
cs3.execute(q)
row=cs3.fetchone
print(row)
while row is not None:
  print(row)
  row = cs3.fetchone()

cs3.close
con.close
```

Output is this

```
select * from toy where tid="10111"
<bound method MySQLCursor.fetchone of <mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor object at 0x10d29b550>>
<bound method MySQLCursor.fetchone of <mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor object at 0x10d29b550>>
```

Comment: `s3.fetchone` should be `s3.fetchone()`

Comment: ```row=cs3.fetchone()```. You forgot the ```()```. This is important because without them, you are just referencing the function without actually calling it.